# Can a Zen Archer Monk making a full attack use snatch arrows?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, combat, monk, actions

Can a Zen Archer Monk making a full attack with a longbow react to subsequent ranged attack against him with deflect or snatch arrows? Or does the full attack require both hands during his entire turn?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need both hands to use a bow, but only during your turn. During enemy turn, you can hold it in one hand and have a free hand to use Snatch Arrows.

It also works when you use a two-handed melee weapon and release your grip on one hand at the end of your turn as a free action (but you won't be able to use your weapon for attacks of opportunity in this case).

From the [combat rules](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/) FAQ :

> *What kind of action is it to remove your hand from a two-handed weapon
>   or re-grab it with both hands?*
>
> Both are free actions. For example, a wizard wielding a quarterstaff
>   can let go of the weapon with one hand as a free action, cast a spell
>   as a standard action, and grasp the weapon again with that hand as a
>   free action; this means the wizard is still able to make attacks of
>   opportunity with the weapon (which requires using two hands).
>
> As with any free action, the GM may decide a reasonable limit to how
>   many times per round you can release and re-grasp the weapon (one
>   release and re-grasp per round is fair).

No matter how you choose to interpret it, you always have a solution to have a free hand during enemy turn.

Comment: You may want to clarify that, while removing your hand from a 2-hander is a legal Free action, it also prevents you from *using* the weapon between your turns (such as for Attacks of Opportunity).

Comment: That is particularly relevant for a Zen Archer, @Ifusaso, since they do end up with the Reflexive Shot ability.

Comment: I like this answer, but can you give me a RAW reference for: "You need both hands to use a bow, but only during your turn. During enemy turn, you can hold it in one hand and have a free hand to use Snatch Arrows."

Comment: @RowleyFalconforge Will logic do? You hold the bow in one hand, the arrow & string in the other. Until you load the bow, your arrow-and-string hand is free.

Comment: I swear this discussion just occurred. Isn't there some debate as to whether a bow is technically a *two-handed weapon* (like a typical greatsword) instead of it just needing two hands to use? (So in the latter case, removing your hand isn't even necessary—you're not using the bow anyway.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan how is this not the case for every two handed weapon? You can rest your pole arm on your shoulder (or the butt on the ground) to free up one hand. Same with a great sword. Two handed weapons are such because they require two hands to ***use,*** not because they are impossible to hold otherwise.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky In such a case, doing so with bow then doesn't require taking the free action *at all*, so if the GM's placed some arbitrary limit on the number of free actions, that limit wouldn't apply. It also saves Dumpster-diving through the FAQ to get the free-action-remove-hand ruling *and*, if true, makes for a more accurate answer.

Comment: This RAW answers the question if I only make a standard attack, one that only requires a standard action.  My question is if I am making a full attack with multiple arrows fired and particularly if I have used a free action before the full attack to activate my boots of speed??

Comment: @HeyICanChan If you think about it... you're already only holding a bow one handed once you've fired your arrow, leaving one of your hands free until you knock and fire your next arrow...